# #next_sync_token not return only updated events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar v3 API and fetching user calendar events. First time when i log in then API gives me all events and nextSyncToken.

Now i change event from calendar and call google api with next Sync Token.

Google api should return events, which are created or update after this sync token.
but google return me old event too.

Please HELP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. 1

Comment: I am experiencing this as well; events that were created well before the timeMin set in the full sync are being returned.